# Getting rid of "theory" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Most of the questions tagged [theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theory) are either closed (because they are advertisements of non-mainstream ideas) or tagged very irrelevantly.

Many people like to pick on meta-tags, I've realised. But as for [theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theory), It is not *even* a meta-tag. I know it is supposed to describe theoretical questions, but since

1. Most of the questions here are theoretical anyway (and in my opinion, that's how it should be).
2. [theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theory) is not a very good description since it makes people think that this is a very good site to come advertise their own non-mainstream ideas, which is not good.

So why not get rid of it? Or rename it as something like [theoretical-physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theoretical-physics) but that isn't as useful as as the tag [experimental-physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experimental-physics), since most questions are theoretical anyway, so it just reduces the limited number of  a maximum of 5 tags.

Comment: In general I'd say get rid of the tag, but there are some questions where it makes sense. E.g. my question about [Lev Landau's “Theoretical Minimum”](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13861/lev-landaus-theoretical-minimum) covers various disciplines (mechanics, solid state physics, field theory) but all from the theoretical side, not from the experimental side. (Also, at least at my university, there is a seperate institute of theoretical physics (as opposed to solid state physics, astrophysics, ...), with its own lectures.)

Comment: @jdm: A question such as yours could be tagged with a few of the relevant disciplines of physics involved.c

Comment: In most cases, yes, but in this case I didn't know what the disciplines were (that was the point of the question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This tag is gone.

[image: BURNINATED]

[Please care for the widows and orphans](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged)

Comment: Ahh... I'll definitely try to do some retagging there. I haven't noticed that the tag existed at all. Because, we already did a bunch of edits a few months ago ;-)

Answer (score 10):

Yes we should get rid of the [theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theory) tag.

Answer (score -1):

No, the [theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theory) tag should stay.